# Sub-navigation bar

Tags: html, css, navigation

I was wondering how would I be able to make a sub nav where only the sub nav changes once I've clicked one of the links in the navigation bar instead of the whole page refreshing if you can help me much appreciated

http://jsfiddle.net/qrn8Q/

Thank you.

**HTML Code:**

```
    <header class="header">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header-primary_container">
            <a class="header_brand" href="#"></a>
            <div class="navigation-primary_right">
                <div class="navigation-primary">
                    <nav class="navigation-primary_links">  <a href="" class="nav_icon selected">Home</a>
                        <a href="" class="nav_icon">Designs</a>
                        <a href="" class="nav_icon">About Us</a>

                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<nav class="sub_nav">
    <a href="index.php" class="sub_nav_icon">Home</a>
    <a href="index.php" class="sub_nav_icon">Sign in</a>
    <a href="index.php" class="sub_nav_icon">Sign up</a>
</nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to use either Ajax or iFrame. For onclick event of those links, you can write your javascript codes to load the new content.

Comment: Thanks for the effort but it didn't really help.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with jQuery. check out my code. it's pretty simple and easy:

http://jsfiddle.net/mELsr/

```
$('.nav_icon').click(function() {
    $('nav.sub_nav:visible').fadeOut(300); // 1
    $('.selected').removeClass('selected'); // 2
    var classKey = $(this).attr('id'); // 3
    $('nav.'+classKey+'_sub_nav').fadeIn(500); // 4
    $(this).addClass('selected'); // 5
    return false; // 6
});
```

In plain english: whenever on of the `.nav_icon`'s is clicked, fade out the visible `sub_nav` (1) and remove `.selected` class from the `.nav_icon` that was selected (2). fetch the clicked item's id attribute (3) and find the `sub_nav` related to it and fade it in (4) and then add `.selected` class to the clicked item (5). at last `return false;` in order to ignore the links default behavior (6).

Hope it help you get started.